# requests slows down after ~ 40 requests

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I am a beginner in python trying to use Beautifulsoup to scrape a website. Problem is the requests start really fast and after around 40 pages, the requests are very slow (I tried to use the print method before and after the requests.get line and identified it is that requests.get that is taking long to respond) , I get like one request per second going through. Anyone had this issue before ? Thanks for your help

Comment: You're being throttled by the server. Slow down.

Comment: thanks for helping @baduker, you mean like using the time.sleep function? do you also have any other suggestion? I have a for loop on million pages in a while loop  and it might take reaaally long. any suggestion is welcome, I don't really know much about scraping. Thanks

Comment: *a for loop on million pages in a while loop* - and you're already getting stuck at page 40? Well, it **will** take some time. Whatever you're scraping see if there's an API or maybe ask for the data you want?

Comment: @baduker yes from 40 it is very slow, unfortunately there is no api for now, alright, thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @elokudzo, if you want to scrape one million pages then you need to consider that you use up a lot of ressources on the web site where you scrape from. If the speed goes down, it seems like the web site doesn't like you scraping it. So maybe have more patience. For example, if you do one request every 5 seconds, that's 17280 a day and you got your scrape done in 2 months. Note that if you try to get around limits, people may notice. The website may introduce captchas or even send false data... (Our own website was hit by scrapers. We had to do stuff like this to scare them off. With success.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.